# Trigger event when uib-accordion is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m trying to trigger an event when the accordion is opened. The event should just get triggered when the accordion is getting opened, not when getting closed.

**HTML:**

```
<uib-accordion>
   <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.open" ng-click="showList(status.open)" 
      ng-init="count=0">
      <uib-accordion-heading>
         I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon"   
          ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 
                     'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
      </uib-accordion-heading>
      {{count}}
   </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

**App.js** (inside the Controller)

```
$scope.showList = function (status){
    if(status)
    {
        $scope.count = $scope.count + 1;
    }
};
```

For the sake of simplicity the event just increments `count` by one. I just want to know how to trigger an event when the accordion is opened.

Answer (score 4):

this is an old thread, but since I bumped into the same issue, here is the solution I came up with.

1. `uib-accordion[-group]` directive has `toggleOpen()` scoped function. so you cannot change that from outside controller.
2. let's override `template` - accordion takes `template-url`. take the original template from:
   https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/accordion/accordion-group.html
   and create your own
3. remove `toggleOpen()` from root `<div>` and `<a>` tags.
4. while you feeding `uib-accordion-heading`, bind click/key-press event with `your controller function` - `ie) myToggleOpen(myIsOpenModel)` make sure your heading covers whole section
5. in `myToggleOpen`, do what you need

---

html

```
<uib-accordion>
  <div uib-accordion-group template-url="myTemplate.html" ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" is-open="item.isOpen">
    <uib-accordion-heading>
      <div ng-click="myToggleOpen(item)">Toggle!</div>
    </uib-accordion-heading>

    <div class="content">
      Hello!
    </div>
  </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

js

```
scope.myToggleOpen = function (item) {
  item.isOpen = !item.isOpen;
}
```

myTemplate.html (change more if needed)

```
<div role="tab" id="{{::headingId}}" aria-selected="{{isOpen}}" class="panel-heading">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href aria-expanded="{{isOpen}}" aria-controls="{{::panelId}}" tabindex="0" class="accordion-toggle" uib-accordion-transclude="heading" ng-disabled="isDisabled" uib-tabindex-toggle><span uib-accordion-header ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}">{{heading}}</span></a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div id="{{::panelId}}" aria-labelledby="{{::headingId}}" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen}}" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" uib-collapse="!isOpen">
  <div class="panel-body" ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for excellent solution for overwriting with a generic accordion template. In case someone stumbles on this, you also need to enclose the divs in myTemplate.html with a `div`, otherwise will get a `Can contain only one root element error`